# Vagrant: Force provisioning ssh to be external ssh (not Ruby's Net::SSH)

Tags: vagrant

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/v2.4.0/vagrantfile/ssh_settings says:

> config.ssh.extra_args (array of strings) - This settings value is
> passed directly into the ssh executable. This allows you to pass any
> arbitrary commands to do things such as reverse tunneling down into
> the SSH program. These options can either be single flags set as
> strings such as "-6" for IPV6 or an array of arguments such as ["-L",
> "8008:localhost:80"] for enabling a tunnel from host port 8008 to port
> 80 on guest. Note: This option only affects the ssh command or
> instances where the SSH executable is invoked **(non-interactive SSH
> connections use the internal SSH communicator which is unaffected by
> this setting).**

For my vagrant box I cannot use Ruby's SSH client.

Can I force Vagrant to use the SSH executable with the config.ssh.extra_args?

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/v2.2.19/other/environmental-variables suggests setting VAGRANT_PREFER_SYSTEM_BIN - but it is unclear to what (I tried true and 1 and exporting the variable - Vagrant 2.2.19 still used Net::SSH).